# Copying and pasting data validations in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to copy a data validation drop down from list D1:D4. Now when I use Paste special to apply the validation to destination cell range, the result is D1:D4 is used for the first destination cell, D2:D5 for the next, D3:D6 for the next and so on but that is not what I want. I want the same range D1:D4 for all destination cells. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to use absolute references. Your original data validation dropdown list should be `$D$1:$D$4`.